# How do I make my python program to write a new file

Tags: python-3.x, persistence

I am writing a program by which I can extract data from a file, and then based on some condition, I have to write that data to other files. These files do not exist and only the code will create these new files. I have tried every possible combination of print parameters but nothing is helping. The program seems to run fine with no error in IDLE but no new files are created. Can somebody give me a solution?

Here is my code:

```
try:
    data= open('sketch.txt')
    for x in data:
        try:
            (person, sentence)= x.split(':',1)"""data is in form of sentences with: symbol present"""
            man=[]      # list to store person 
            other=[]     #list to store sentence
            if person=="Man":
                man.append(sentence)
            elif person=="Other Man":
                other.append(sentence)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    data.close()
except IOError:
    print("file not found")
    try:
        man_file=open("man_file.txt","w")""" otherman_file and man_file are for storing data"""
        otherman_file=open("otherman_file.txt", "w")
        print(man,file= man_file.txt)
        print(other, file=otherman_file.txt)
        man_file.close()
        otherman_file.close()
    except IOError:
        print ("file error")
```

Comment: please add sketch.txt data format

Comment: this is my sketch.txt-
1.Man: Is this the right room for an argument?
2.Other Man: I've told you once.
3.Man: No you haven't!
4.Other Man: Yes I have.
5.Man: When?
6.Other Man: Just now.

Comment: Indentation for the second except seems wrong.

Comment: I am new here, so just getting used to. BTW there is no indentation error in my IDLE. Its just happening here. I have now improved my indentation here

Comment: @Naor Tedgi  can u check with the sketch.txt I have given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 problems

1. you should use

   ```
    man_file = open("man_file.txt", "w+")
   otherman_file = open("otherman_file.txt", "w+")
   ```

> w+  -  create file if it doesn't exist and open it in write mode
>
> Modes 'r+', 'w+' and 'a+' open the file for updating (reading and writing); note that 'w+' truncates the file..

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

2.

```
  print(man,file= man_file.txt)
  print(other, file=otherman_file.txt)
```

if sketch.txt file do not exist then "man" and "other"  will not initialized
and in the print method will throw another exception

**try to run this script**

```
def func():
    man = []      # list to store person
    other = []  # list to store sentence
    try:
        data = open('sketch.txt', 'r')
        for x in data:
            try:
                (person, sentence) = x.split(':', 1)

                if person == "Man":
                    man.append(sentence)
                elif person == "Other Man":
                    other.append(sentence)
            except ValueError:
                pass
        data.close()
    except IOError:
        print("file not found")
    try:
        man_file = open("man_file.txt", "w+")
        otherman_file = open("otherman_file.txt", "w+")
    #        print(man, man_file.txt)
    #       print(other, otherman_file.txt)
        man_file.close()
        otherman_file.close()
    except IOError:
        print ("file error")


func()
```

Comment: @rachit saini let me know if it help you

Comment: this is my sketch.txt- 1.Man: Is this the right room for an argument? 2.Other Man: I've told you once. 3.Man: No you haven't! 4.Other Man: Yes I have. 5.Man: When? 6.Other Man: Just now.

Also I have tried r+, w+, a+ but they seem to be not working either. Is there some admin rights that are not allowing this thing to take place

Comment: which OS do you use  ? i have a strange feeling that the file is been created but not in the current directory that the script is runing

Comment: windows 7 64 bits
Should I gave a full fledged path for the new files man_file.txt and otherman_file.txt

Comment: run a simple search for the file please

Comment: remove this 2 lines and run again please .    print(man,file= man_file.txt)
  print(other, file=otherman_file.txt)

Comment: nothing seem to happen. I think there are some issue with the admin rights which are not allowng python to create these files. Can that be possible@Naor Tedgi

Comment: did you run a search for the files in different directory? and its not most likely it depends on the  script current directory  permissions

Comment: @rachitsaini i add a snippet to my answer try it and let me know if it works

Comment: I dont know how but it has happened now, and my last code is also working fine now. but they both are just creating the files, but are not writing anything in the files

Comment: which script did you run? the one i added or yours?

Comment: Ya yours is running fine and mine had some indentation issue for the last try .everything is working fine now!! Thanks a lot